# Is it possible to 'unflag' a question?

Tags: support, flagging

Somehow..., I thought I was on meta TeX.SX and saw a question that belonged on TeX.SX, so I flagged it.

Immediately after I flagged it, I realized...uh, embarrassingly enough,...that I was on the main TeX.SX site.

Is it possible to 'unflag' a question that you've flagged?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As of now, [unflagging is](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87660/168244) [not possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87500/168244)<sup>*</sup>, most likely because it doesn't happen often enough to warrant special treatment in this way.

Possible ways of "unflagging":

- Visit the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends), find one of the mods and profusely apologize. :) They may be able to dismiss a flag and avoid it from spreading to the review queues.
- If mods aren't directly available in chat, re-flag the question, this time specifically "for moderator attention" and state that it was an an incorrect flag.
- One may also want to drop a comment in the post thread to guard others from accepting the flag as-is (out of ignorance and/or [possible](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/badges/211/custodian) [badge](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/badges/128/reviewer) [hunting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/badges/212/steward) within review queues)

"Misflagging" should not be a problem if it is not chronic.

<sub><sup>*</sup> This may change, just like the network added a way to [revert close votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/915/168244) (2013-07-15). [Something similar was done for comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1170/168244) (2012-04-12).</sub>